# pyspark cannot generate job when reading big table by sqlquery

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I use pyspark to read a big table, but I cannot find running job in webui's Jobs tab.
In webui's Executors tab, only 2 executors in active. Others are dead.
In webui's SQL tab, have a running Query.The query always continuing almost one hour then the job will running.
[image]
[image]
code as below:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.\
        config('spark.executor.memory', '12g').\
        config('spark.executor.cores', '3').\
        config('spark.driver.memory','16g').\
        config('spark.executor.instances', '60').\
        config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '50g').\
        config("spark.driver.cores", '4').\
        config('spark.default.parallelism', '360').\
        config('spark.task.cpus', '1').\
        config('hive.exec.orc.split.strategy','ETL').\
        config("spark.yarn.queue","DataBusinessDept_Risk_Query").\
        config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").\
        config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").\
        config('spark.rpc.message.maxSize', '512').\
        config('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic').\
        config('spark.sql.getSplit.parallelism.num', '180').\
        appName('test').\
        enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

a = spark.sql("""
        select t2.*
          from table_name t2
         where pt between '20210401' and '20210416'
""").cache()
a.count()
```

Comment: how many rows for your query?

Comment: @Lamanus the query with where clause almost have 38400 partitions, 12 billion rows, 1T  disk space with orc format.

Comment: `where pt between '20210401' and '20210416'` for this time period? is `pt` a partition key? if not, then this is expected...

Comment: @Lamanus pt is partition key. but this table have three partition keys.I guess much time used for gc in I/O period because of large data, so the job can't be generated quickly？